# On what port Pyrax connects to rackspace cloud containers?

Tags: python, cloud, samba, pyrax

I am using pyrax for transferring my media files to rackspace cloud files.
But since we implemented user authentication using samba in our office pyrax fails to connect to cloud containers on development machine.
So i want to know on what port pyrax connect to rackspace cloud containers so that i can ask my samba server to allow pyrax on that port.

Answer (score 1):

All of the Rackspace APIs are accessed over port 443 from pyrax.

Comment: 35357 is used for what?